# why addclass, removeclass is not working on foreach in js?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I want to add a class on img tag when hover over the h1 tag, I try this code, but it's not working
I try to to add it, but the foreach give me an error, but if I remove this `imgg.classList.add("ishover");` and console it, I can get the console perfectly, didn't get any error, but when I put this code `imgg.classList.add("ishover");` in foreach, it's give me error every time, the error like "imgg.classList is undefined".

```
    <div id="section">
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h1>Scaleboot</h1>
      <img src="./img.gif" />
    </div>
    <h2>
      Service to validate minimum viable products & launch them successfully
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h1>Scaleboot</h1>
      <img src="./img.gif" />
    </div>
    <h2>
      Service to validate minimum viable products & launch them successfully
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h1>Scaleboot</h1>
      <img src="./img.gif" />
    </div>
    <h2>
      Service to validate minimum viable products & launch them successfully
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const imgg = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  const item = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
  item.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      imgg.classList.add("ishover");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If you want that class to be gone on unhovering, a simple css could be enough. Like [`h1:hover ~ img{background: red}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

`imgg` is the list of images, you need to index it to add the class to a specific image. `forEach()` passes an array index, you can use that to index into `imgg`.

```
  item.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      imgg[i].classList.add("ishover");
    });
  });
```